# Как рассчитать сумму двух табличных частей в 1С:Предприятие 8.3?

Tags: 1с

В справочнике присутствуют две табличные части, внутри каждой есть поля **Наименование**, **Количество**, **Цена**, **Сумма**.
Чтобы рассчитать сумму двух табличных частей было решено рассчитать сначала общую сумму одной, а затем второй. Для расчета у каждой табличной части нашел такие поля, как **ИтогСумма**, если добавить их на форму, то можно увидеть сумму каждой из табличной части.

Появился вопрос как сложить их вместе, чтобы получить сумму двух табличных частей. Создал поле **Цена** (тип данных Число) для справочника и попытался присвоить данному полю значение из **ИтогСумма** одной из табличной части (например, из табл. части Материалы). Однако я не смог обратиться к данным поля **ИтогСумма**.
Я писал так:

```
Объект.Цена = Элементы.МатериалыИтогСумма;
```

Но в результате поле **Цена** отображало лишь значение 0.

Может кто подсказать каким образом обратиться к полю **ИтогСумма** табличной части и взять оттуда число, чтобы можно было сложить их для расчета суммы двух табличных частей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так

```
Объект.Цена = Объект.<ИмяТабличнойЧасти1>.Итог("ИмяКолонки") + Объект.<ИмяТабличнойЧасти2>.Итог("ИмяКолонки");
```